# componentRestrictions never returns no results found, even when searching for locations outside the restrictions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When you set the value of a componentRestrictions to a country or administrativeArea, and you search for a location that is 100% not in that country / administrativeArea, it will always center on the value of the componentRestrictions instead of saying that no results can be found.

Is there a way to make it actually say no results found ( zero_results api response ), which I feel is the only correct answer?

You can see [this here](https://jsfiddle.net/fruLhdk3/). Just search for Amsterdam, New York etc. It doesn't exists in Australia  so I would expect no results found instead of it being centered on Australia.

This is how I restricted it to Australia in the test example.

```
    geocode({ address: inputText.value, componentRestrictions: { country: "AU" } })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google says](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243780835#comment6) that this is intentional behavior:

> if a result is not found within the filters specified by the components parameter, the Geocoding API would normally return the filter itself, although it may occasionally return ZERO_RESULTS instead. Both results are considered intended behavior.

What you can do is check if it's a partial match, using the `partial_match` property and compare the `short_name` of the `address_components` item to see if it matches with the country filter, for example:

```js
if(results[0].partial_match && results[0].address_components[0].short_name === "AU")
    throw new Error("Match was found but not within the filter.");
```

Comment: Hmm, I checked the documentation for this so many times but still managed to overlook it. Will do what you suggest in the code, and do a manual check. Thanks :)